# Setting a pointer to a specific array and/or struct element

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

Here is the scenario:

I have an array, `AllElements` of structure `ElementSet`, and inside of that structure - is a set of `myElement` structures and also an array of `myElement` structures. This is basically serving as an organized static data collection of which I sometimes need to access an individual member of.

Here are the code snippets of the declarations:

### In Header (.h) File:

```
typedef struct myElement
{

    uint32        then;                                                                                   
    uint32        now;                                                                                    
    bool          isInitialized;
                                                            
} myElement;
```

### In a function in the Program (.c) File:

```
const int8 numElements = 8;
const int8 numSubElements = 4;

static struct ElementSet {
    
    struct myElement CN;                       
    struct myElement CC[numSubElements];      
    struct myElement CP;                       
    struct myElement CR;                       
    
} ElementSet;

  static struct ElementSet AllElements[numElements];
```

I have another function in which I need to pass a pointer to a `myElement` struct to perform an operation.

So, I have to create a pointer to a `myElement` struct, easy enough:

```
  struct myElement      *thisElement
```

Now I select my element based on inputs passed to the function. So, I may need to, for example, access the data in the element defined by, for example, `AllElements[3].CN`, or `AllElements[7].CC[3]`

Are the assignments this simple?

```
thisElement = &AllElements[3].CN;

thisElement = &AllElements[7].CC[3];
```

Or is there something different I need to do to make sure I'm accessing exactly the element I need?

Comment: The first is wrong, it should be `&AllElements[3].CN`

Comment: Why don't you try it? `thisElement = &AllElements[3];` Clearly that can't be correct as the type being assigned, `ElementSet *`, doesn't match the type being assigned to, `struct myElement *`. The compiler will immediately tell you that.  But yes if you want to have a pointer to an array element it is as simple as taking the address of it and assigning to a pointer variable of the same type.

Comment: There's a nice playpit [here](https://wandbox.org/) (other playpits are available).

Comment: I prefer straight up pointer math, `thisElement = AllElements[7].CC+3;` , but that's personal, I suppose.  The first assignment, `thisElement = &AllElements[3];` is complete nonsense, however. The wrong types and compiler warnings/errors should be evidence enough of that.

Comment: @kaylum see Barmar's comment... I have now corrected

Comment: @WhozCraig - same mistake pointed out by Barmar and kaylum... now corrected. Error of omission. That was not missing in actual code, I left it out when transferring to here.

Comment: I figured it was just a copying mistake. Your general understanding is correct, it's really this simple.

Comment: Thanks @PaulSanders - I haven't used Wandbox before, but I've used similar for web-based coding like JavaScript. I don't know why I didn't consider looking for that for C. It's hard when my target is another machine and I can't test on my own - but this works.

Comment: @Trashman cool.